# ImportError: No module named with subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, python-import

I have my application organised with this structure:

```
main/
    config/
        __init__.py
        # some source .py files
    date/
        __init__.py
        # some source .py files

    # some other sources/packages
    main.py
    __init__.py

bin/
    app
```

**The names above are only examples.

The `app` file is also a Python file that inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` calls the main function of the `main.py` file.

This application is working well, it works from everywhere, running the `app` file. We also have uploaded the package on PyPI and there are no problems.

Now I'm trying to write some regression tests (another Python sources) that calls the main application. These tests, what basically do is:

With `subprocess` module and its function `check_output`, I'm running the `app` file, so I'm running something similar to

```
subprocess.check_output('..\bin\app')
```

The problem appears when I run my regression tests, then I get an `ImportError: No module named` error. I've tried some different things but I'm not able to run my regression tests..

The modules not found are those ones that are inside my application, for example inside the `config` directory. I've tried refactoring some things, but always there's something failing with the same error. However, as my application works well when I run it normally, I think that the error is another one, something strange..

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with `subprocess.check_output('..\bin\app')`. It is similar to running `..\bin\app` in *unix shell*. Does this work in shell?

Comment: Yes, as I said, I'm writting some regression tests. My idea is to write some Python code that automates a normal usage (CLI) of the application and then checks the outputs, etc. Yes, I also said that the application works with a normal usage (running it `..\bin\app`) in a *unix* shell.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't pasted the full error message. There's shouldn't be anything stopping you from importing `subprocess`. Maybe you misspelled it:

```
>>> import subproces
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named subproces
>>> import subprocess
>>>
```

You've got another issue with your code for `subprocess.check_output`. Assuming there's nothing else wrong in your code or folder structure that affect the import, change

```
subprocess.check_output('..\bin\app')
```

to

```
subprocess.check_output('..\\bin\\app')
```

---

In Python and in many other languages, `\` is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). Just as `\n` is the escape *sequence* for a newline, `\a` is 'beep' and `\b` is 'backspace'.

To see that in action:

```
>>> print 'hello\bworld'  # notice the missing letter in the output
hellworld
>>> print '\a'  # you'd hear a beep

>>>
```

So your string `'..\bin\app'` gets interpreted as `'..<backspace>in<bell>pp'`:

```
>>> print '..\bin\app'
.inpp
```

and you'd hear a beep. So it's unlikely that you'd have a file with that name, and with a beep in its name*.

In order to prevent the backslash (`\`) from behaving like an escape character, you have to escape that too with a backslash before it: `'\\'`

```
>>> print '..\\bin\\app'
..\bin\app
```

** (some filesystems theoretically allow that)*